# OpenCV and python can not find shared libraries

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4 with Python 2.7.
I want my script to be able to run on a machine that does not have the opencv library, so I copied in the working dir all the .so files needed in a dir opencv. With sys, I appended the path to see this directory.
When I import cv2 the following error occurs:

ImportError: libopencv_contrib.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The thing is that the specific file exists in the opecv dir I created and added to the path.

Does anyone knows how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Can't you just install it. I did a similiar task by providing a docker container.

Comment: The problem is that it needs to work in any University computer right away, so installing it on every machine is not possible :(

Comment: Have you tried to expand the LD_LIBRARY_PATH? Something like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/myopencvdirectory`

Comment: This seems to work, although now it says that the gcc compiler version is missing :P